# Footer section is missing in some product listing page

Tags: magento

My problem is that when I am clicking on a category,it will show the products of that category but footer section is not coming. Footer section  shows only in 2-3 product listing page of a particular category.I want that footer section will show in all product listing page of all categories.
showing error

Fatal error:  Class 'TheCartPress' not found in /home1/griar/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/Riar-Inc/template/checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml on line 67

I have tried to find the error but unable to do that.
If anybody knows then please help me out!
Thanks!
the code `/home1/griar/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/Riar-Inc/template/checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml` is

```
<?php $shoppingCart = TheCartPress::getShoppingCart();
printf( '%s item(s) in your <a href="%s">bag</a> – <a href="%s">Checkout</a>', $shoppingCart->getCount(), tcp_get_the_shopping_cart_url(), tcp_get_the_checkout_url() ); ?>

<?php if ($this->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()):?>

<div class="block block-cart">

    <?php $_cartQty = $this->getSummaryCount() ?>

    <div class="block-title">

        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('My Cart') ?></span></strong>

    </div>

    <div class="block-content">

    <?php if ($_cartQty>0): ?>

        <div class="summary">

            <?php if ($_cartQty==1): ?>


                <p class="amount"><?php echo $this->__('There is <a href="%s">1 item</a> in your cart.', $this->getUrl('checkout/cart')) ?></p>

            <?php else: ?>

                <p class="amount"><?php echo $this->__('There are <a href="%s">%s items</a> in your cart.', $this->getUrl('checkout/cart'), $_cartQty) ?></p>

            <?php endif ?>

            <p class="subtotal">

                <?php if ($this->canApplyMsrp()): ?>

                    <span class="map-cart-sidebar-total"><?php echo $this->__('ORDER TOTAL WILL BE DISPLAYED BEFORE YOU SUBMIT THE ORDER'); ?></span>

                <?php else: ?>

                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Cart Subtotal:') ?></span> <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getSubtotal()) ?>

                    <?php if ($_subtotalInclTax = $this->getSubtotalInclTax()): ?>

                        <br />(<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_subtotalInclTax) ?> <?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->getIncExcText(true) ?>)

                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endif; ?>

            </p>

        </div>

    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if($_cartQty && $this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()): ?>

    <div class="actions">

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_actions') ?>

        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?>" class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?></span></span></button>

    </div>

    <?php endif ?>

    <?php $_items = $this->getRecentItems() ?>

    <?php if(count($_items)): ?>

        <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Recently added item(s)') ?></p>

        <ol id="cart-sidebar" class="mini-products-list">

        <?php foreach($_items as $_item): ?>

            <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

        </ol>

        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('cart-sidebar', 'none-recursive')</script>

    <?php else: ?>

        <p class="empty"><?php echo $this->__('You have no items in your shopping cart.') ?></p>

    <?php endif ?>

    </div>

</div>

<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Plz help me to solve this problem

Comment: Are you using same footer for all the pages?

Comment: yes, I am using the same footer in all the pages then also it is not coming

Comment: One more question. Is it a single `list.phtml` used for the product listing page or different for different category pages?

Comment: single list.phtml is used.....I showed all the categories in the left menu.When i clicked on a category,then all products present in that category is shown but footer section is not coming...only in 1 category, footer section is coming.i don't understand why footer is coming only in one category page why not in others though i have used only 1 footer.phtml and 1 list.phtml for all categories

Comment: Can you post what is written in the file /home1/griar/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/Riar-Inc/template/checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml on line 67?

Comment: I didn't get any solution yet now.if anyone knows anything about this,then please tell me.It is very urgent